# How can I view my pdf in jquery pdf viewer?

Tags: jquery, pdf, viewer

I downloaded this pdf viewer (Stable version):

http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

When I open `viewer.html` locally, everything works fine. I see the pdf in my browser.

I uploaded the folder exactly as it is on my website, but when I open the page `viewer.html` online I do not see a pdf.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: could you post if there is any error message on Browser Console?  did you change "<script src="../build/pdf.js"></script>" to "<script src="build/pdf.js"></script>"

Comment: In the cosole it is Loading error for <script> with source "https://mypage.com/build/pdf.js".

Comment: and do you have pdf.js in build folder under root of your website?

Comment: ah this folder was missing! Now it is working. Thank you!!